# intel i5 2400 cpu on this Asus mobo H61M-K, any concern

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cooling, temperature

My CPU is intel i5 2400 
spec:http://ark.intel.com/products/52207/Intel-Core-i5-2400-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz

My mobo is Asus H61M-K , which is a really basic board, but newly bought yesterday, to replace the defected board earlier. 
spec: https://www.asus.com/ph/Motherboards/H61MK/specifications/

However, according to the specification in the above official site, my CPU's TDP is 95W while my Asus board is "Supports CPU up to 77 W"

It's the motherboard advised by the technician because he said it's the last board now that can support my CPU which is also MATX and it's fine perfectly. My PC is now ON, working fine now, after 12 hours, but would that mean I ll be having problems later like heat issue, fry or damage my CPU or other hardware?

Comment: I wonder if there's any way to underclock your CPU (lower the speed of it in general, while lowering the maximum power it can use)

it's too bad you decided to buy a 2011 model cpu instead of a 2015 or newer. They are much more energy efficient so you can get away with buying a weaker power supply, probably save some money.

http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i5-2400-vs-Intel-Core-i5-6400/803vs3512

Also has much upgraded graphics if you plan on using integrated ones.

http://ark.intel.com/products/88185/Intel-Core-i5-6400-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz

Comment: If you want to be more independant at building your PCs, take note that by looking at the Intel spec for your i5 2400, it says:
Package Specifications:
Sockets Supported  LGA1155

That means you need to search for a motherboard that has a LGA1155 socket.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&IsNodeId=1&N=100007627%20600093976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to give a definitive answer on this one. You might be getting different opinions from posting elsewhere because some people have tried it and it fried out their motherboard, while others did it and got lucky and never had any such failures.

You're not posing an extra risk to your CPU. You are, however, posing some extra risk to your motherboard failing. It is rated to support up to 77W. Can it go a little over 77W without damaging it? Sure, most likely it can go a bit beyond the 77W it supports. Like with a lot of other things, the manufacturer will be somewhat conservative when listing a maximum support limit. Your processor will push it beyond it's supported limit. There's no telling how long your motherboard will run before frying out. And it may never fry out. I think the only thing that is safe to say is that using that processor with that motherboard will shorten the expected lifespan of the motherboard--maybe by a little, maybe by a lot, but there's no way to be sure right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your processor is an i5-2400 at 3.4 Ghz (according to your numbers).  That board only supports i5-2400 up to 2.4 ghz.  Multiple numbers contradict.

Did a technician support his recommendation with spec numbers? Subjective claims are hearsay.  View spec numbers.  Asus does not list that CPU as supported by that motherboard.